# How to get the correct position of an Image in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am a beginner in Windows Presentation Foundation.
I have a Canvas in which there is a small square canvas. Inside this small square canvas i have an image.
I have attached an event handler to this image , When user click on this image user can get the current position of the image.

Whenever user click on that image , he/she will get a prompt message box in which user get the current image position to print.

Everything is working fine when user press Left click on the image .
But, the problem arises when user first pressing the right click on the image and suddenly pressing Left click on the same image , It is not showing the same value.

I have not attached any event handler on the right click.

I am using the following code :

```
Image objImage = new Image();
objImage .Height =12;   
objImage .Width = 12;
objImage .Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;                 
imageAck.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(objImageMouseLeftButtonDown);

private void objImageMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Point mouseCurrent = e.GetPosition(null);
}
```

I am notgetting the same value in mouseCurrent

Comment: We cannot reproduce your error from your small code example... please provide a *minimal code example that reproduces your error*.

Answer (score 2):

Using `e.GetPosition`, this gets the position of the mouse pointer **relative** to the element that was clicked, not the canvas that the element belongs to.

To get the actual position of the image on the `Canvas`, you need to use the `Canvas.GetLeft`, and `Canvas.GetTop` methods. Here is an example:

```
private void objImageMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    double left = Canvas.GetLeft((UIElement)sender);
    double top = Canvas.GetTop((UIElement)sender);
}
```

You can then use the `left` and `top` variables for whatever purpose you need.

Comment: Actually i want to show my user control (In which i show the position of the mouse) with the same position that of my image . I mean image click position and user control position should be the same.  Can i use above code ?

Comment: Just to confirm. Click Image -> User Control moves to the Image location? If so, you can use `Canvas.SetLeft` and `Canvas.SetTop` to set the position of your User Control to the `left` and `top` variables I provided in my sample code.

Comment: I am getting left = NaN but top = -2 ; But when i was using mouseCurrent the value is 678,408. I want exactly the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got an answer by Googling some hour .....

```
  Point currentMousePosition = Mouse.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow);
```